# MockMvc test returns 404 instead of 200 without a leading "/" in url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockmvc

With Spring boot 1.5.9 and following:

```html
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class BigPoolControllerMockMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetDisplayPools() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get(CONTROLLER_PATH + DISPLAY_POOLS_API + "?param=abc")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


}
```

I keep getting:
WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [api/v1/app/pool] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the URL needs to begin with a "/" for mockmvc request to find it:

```html
  @Test
    public void testGetDisplayPools() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/" + CONTROLLER_PATH + DISPLAY_POOLS_API + "?amazonRegionCode=us-west-1")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

The leading "/" works. Thanks to this post: https://blmte.com/computer-internet-technology/2416430_spring-test-returning-404-instead-of-200-in-testing-rest-api-in-spring-boot